# How i can get the parent id in html code. In selenium webdirver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how i can get the parent id in following html code. using description class name i want to fetch id of that div.there is card-box class name is common for all the div and id is generated at run time.

```
 <div id="2321-79" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-32" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-33" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-81" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-74" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-59" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-80" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-35" class="card-box"></div>
    <div id="2321-84" class="card-box">
        <div class="card overdue white">
            <div class="summary"></div>
            <div class="info" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2321-82" class="card-box">
        <div class="card overdue white">
            <div class="summary">
                <a class="pic" href="/profiles/219"></a>
                <div class="detail">
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <span class="description"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                <div class="team">
                    <table width="100%" style="padding: 0px 10px">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="from" colspan="4">


                                                  From


                                    <a href="/profiles/219"></a>


                                                  to


                                    <a href="/profiles/1"></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="20%"></td>
                                <td width="50%"></td>
                                <td width="7%"></td>
                                <td width="20%"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <form method="post" data-remote="true" action="/commitments/get_view" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
                        <input id="col_type" type="hidden" value="col_my_work_commitments" name="col_type"></input>
                        <input id="card_id" type="hidden" value="174" name="card_id"></input>
                        <input id="state" type="hidden" value="published" name="state"></input>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="actions">
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="commitments-identifier" type="submit" name="btn_discuss"></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

for this i m tried this code

```
    String val1 = "Final";
    List<WebElement> resultList1 = card1.findElements(By.className("description"));
    for (WebElement resultItem : resultList1){
           String tabname=resultItem.getText();
           if(tabname.contentEquals(val1))
           {
               System.out.println(description.getAttribute("id"));
               resultItem.click();                 
               break;
           }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some `WebElement el`, and you want to get its parent `WebElement`, you could use:

```
el.findElement(By.xpath(".."))
```

To get *that* element's `id`, you could use:

```
el.findElement(By.xpath("..")).getAttribute("id")
```

Comment: thanks siking for ur reply. here i can not use xpath because these fields generate at run time.can u suggest any alternative of xpath

Comment: @AnantJain I do not understand your requirement.